# Printer issue in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, printer

My Printer Spooler stops working automatically. I have restarted Printer spooler many times, but it just stops automatically. Due to that I cannot properly use my printer. Please help me.

Comment: Have a look [Here](https://www.techsupportall.com/print-spooler-keeps-stopping-automatically/)

Comment: Please provide error messages, if any, please ensure your drivers are up to date. Please provide model number of printer.

Answer (score 0):

Nearly all print spooler problems are caused by a driver problem. The best thing to do is to reinstall the driver, as follows.

Go to Devices and Printers. Delete the printer. Then click on any other printer (XPS, fax, etc) and a menu will appear at the top. Click on Print Server Properties, and then on the Drivers tab. Remove any instances of your printer from the list. Now reinstall from the CD or from a freshly downloaded copy of the driver.